# Stepper motor for ebike

Tags: electric-bike

In these days I'm going to design a e bike project. I'm going to use BLDC motor for that. but normally (according to my knowledge) there are two types of BLDC motors. there are, normal BLDC motor and stepper motor. my problem in can I use a Large stepper motor for the e bike?

Comment: While it wouldn't be impossible to use a stepper motor and there may even be some advantages if you're going to use the motor from a standing start it's not likely to be ideal. Whatever motor you use will also need integrating with the drive chain. Kits are available with hub motors for the front or rear wheel. These are DC motors in every kit I've looked at, and from what I've seen the control circuit is usually some form of PWM. The hub motors are also available for you to build your own wheel but this would be an expensive option.

Comment: @Chris thanks. please let me know if i go for a stepper motor(integrated as side motor not a hub motor) is it possible?

Comment: Seems like a better question for the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've got the hilltopper retrofit kit, and its got a three phase AC motor in the front wheel.  So there's heaps of options, do some research online.  http://electric-bike-kit-forum.com/ may be a good start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stepper motors have very poor maximum RPMs and dreadful torque at high rpm. Also, controlling stepper motors requires a special controller and it's hard to find high amperage controllers. High-amperage stepper motors are also very expensive.

There's really no advantage to using a stepper motor. You don't need its precision (you can tell a stepper to rotate CW 145 degrees then back CCW 32 degrees, but why would you need that in an e-bike).

Go with an appropriate brushless motor.

Answer (score 2):

Stepper motors are generally used for servo (positioning) applications.  They work great in Shimano's Di2 electronic derailleurs (obviously a positioner).  But your application is straight velocity mode, stick with BLDC.